# English Translation of Rabbi Chaim Volozhin's Nefesh ha-Chaim?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, translation, nefesh-hachaim

I need to find an English translation of Nefesh Hachaim.  Preferably one that is gratis on the World Wide Web.  Thanks!

Comment: http://www.seforimcenter.com/product.asp?P_ID=5302&strPageHistory=search&strKeywords=nefesh,hachaim&numPageStartPosition=1&strSearchCriteria=all&PT_ID=all

Comment: See this related answer: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/127921/11501

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you will find it online for free, but [Nefesh Hachaim By Rav Chaim of Volozhin Translated by: Rabbi Avraham Yaakov Finkel](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/476332223) is very good. He does not translate some of the kabbalistic ideas though.

Comment: Does there exist one online that is not free?

Comment: He does translate most of the Kabbalistic ideas though.

Comment: Amazon link: http://amazon.com/dp/1607630214

Comment: @AdamMosheh It appears there is a [Kindle version](http://amazon.com/dp/B005JVSGHE) available and Amazon's Kindle app is available for both desktop or mobile devices.

Answer (score 4):

There is now a complete English translation:

[http://www.amazon.com/The-Soul-Life-Complete-Ha-chayyim/dp/061569991X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/061569991X)

Comment: Hi LenMinNJ and welcome to mi.yodeya. Thanks for the recommendation! See you around the site.

Comment: I forgot about this question I asked last year. And I remember seeing it on Hirhurim here: http://torahmusings.com/2012/10/books-received-47/ ... But my question is still can I find it online for free. I have not yet given up hope!

Comment: Here it is, for free: http://chazarahmp3.com/uploads/3/4/1/8/34183995/03_nefesh_hachaim_website.pdf

Comment: Are you the author of this translation?

Answer (score 2):

Fraenkel, Avinoam (trans./comm.) Nefesh HaTzimtzum: Rabbi Cahim Volozhin’s Nefesh HaChaim with Translation and Commentary, two volumes (Jerusalem – New York: Urim Publications, 2015).
This edition provides the complete Nefesh HaChaim in English and Hebrew, along with a wealth of supplementary material, including a “deeply Kabbalistic” tract by Rabbi Yitzchak, Rabbi Chaim’s son, known by the title Maamar BeTzeLeM, DISCOURSE ON THE IMAGE.

The two-volume set can be purchased for about $60 (e.g., at Z Berman, Seforim Center, or Urim Publications).
Alas, no free sources discovered so far.

Comment: Please show the correct link and if it is a free web translation or if it is a copy to be purchased.

Comment: Hello sabbahillel - please note the addition re Nefesh haHayyim.