# Nefesh HaChaim - Edition

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, nefesh-hachaim

Can someone recommend an edition of Nefesh HaChaim? I am looking for a nice edition with clear type and explanatory notes.

Comment: Nefesh Hatzimtzum

Comment: When asking these questions, it would be helpful to specify if English or Hebrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have [this](https://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=9791&strReferer=search&PPGR=0) edition at home - the print is very clear and it has an explanatory commentary entitled U'vecharta Bachaim - you can see sample pages [here](https://seforimcenter.com/showScannedImages.aspx?pfile=6720.gif).

However I have also seen [this](https://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=7805&strReferer=search&PPGR=0) version which is very nice with a commentary by Rabbi Yisrael Eliyahu Weintraub called Biyur Yiras Chaim. You can see samples [here](https://seforimcenter.com/showScannedImages.aspx?pfile=7805.gif).

Finally when searching further, you might be interested in [this](https://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=10977&strReferer=search&PPGR=0) edition which has explanations entitled Peirush Meir HaEtz from Rabbi Yehoshua Lipschitz - see samples [here](https://seforimcenter.com/showScannedImages.aspx?pfile=10977.gif)

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I am unclear if you are looking for Hebrew or English. If the latter, then Avinoam Fraenkel has translated the entirety of Nefesh Hachaim (unlike some of the other translations which skip content or full chapters).

His translation, [Nefesh Hatzimtzum](https://avinoamfraenkel.com/nefesh-hatzimtzum/) comes out in two volumes and has lots of commentary, explanations and massive amount of footnotes. It is extremely clear and well-done. Volume 1 has the full translation, volume has related writings and a long essay on the concept of *tzimtzum*. Volume 1 has the full Hebrew text as well (newly typeset in perfect font). See the *haskamot* on the site as well.

Happy to share some page pictures if helpful.

Other translations into English include [R Avraham Yaakov Finkel](https://www.judaicapress.com/products/nefesh-hachaim)'s (but there is no Hebrew and no translation of the Kabbalistic matters) and [Eliezer Lipa Moskowitz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/061569991X)'s which is more complete and includes facsimiles of the 1837 edition (in *ktav Rashi*).

Answer (score 1):

Sefaria offers the **online** English-version of Nefesh HaChayim from Rabbi Chaim of Volozhin. I would recommend the version/translation called ["The Soul of Life, translated by Leonard Moskowitz, Teaneck, NJ 2012 [Rev. 1.5]](https://www.sefaria.org/Nefesh_HaChayim%2C_An_Introduction_by_the_Author%27s_Son.1?ven=The_Soul_of_Life,_translated_by_Leonard_Moskowitz,_Teaneck,_NJ_2012_%5BRev._1.5%5D&lang=bi&with=Translations&lang2=en)". You can choose this by clicking on "translations".

See also this related post: [English Translation of Rabbi Chaim Volozhin's Nefesh ha-Chaim?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/29110/27180)